# How to make only one piece of data affected by UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

So I just did a bit of research on UserDefaults last night and this morning and I wanna know how I can use dictionaries in a certain way. My issue is that when a user presses a certain button and the UserDefaults dictionary data gets set, every piece of data in the app is affected as well. My goal is to just have that piece of data affected only and the rest stay the same as they were before.

```
    let eventDict = ["eventName": "\(selectedEventName!)", "purchased": true] as [String : Any]
```

This is the dictionary I set, pretty simple. And when the button is pressed I run this line of code.

```
self.defaults.set(eventDict, forKey: "eventDict")
```

These work perfect and I check the .plist file and everything is correct, it shows the event name and the purchased as 1 (true).

Now I tried to add some logic, in my `viewDidLoad()` of the page I purchase the event on and it works but when I check every other event the page has the same outcome, which is not what I want.

```
 let checkEventStatus = defaults.dictionary(forKey: "eventDict")
    
    
    if checkEventStatus?.isEmpty == false {
        viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
        cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = false
        purchaseTicketButton.isHidden = true
        creditCard.isHidden = true
    } else {
        viewPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
        cancelPurchaseButton.isHidden = true
    }
```

I couldn't figure out how to retrieve an exact value from a key in a dictionary, so I just used `isEmpty()` instead which I thought would make sense because if the event wasn't purchased, it wouldn't have a dictionary with it's name in it.

[image: buttons in VC]

These are the buttons I want to show up when the purchase button is pressed. The purchase button is hidden right now because it was already pressed, so the UserDefault data is set, and that effects the button visibility. Now when I check every other event, the screen is the same. I just want each screen to be a certain way depending on if the event is purchased or not using UserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a fundamental problem - you're not actually saving any purchase status liked to an event in the first place, so there's no way you'll be able to determine the status for an event and set the button status accordingly.  You need a data structure that associates the event name with the event status.

I think you'll need more thought into your data and workflow, but as a trival example that might get you started, you could create a Event struct to hold both name and status.  You could also build in the purchase date and cost...

```
struct Event {
  name: String
  purchased: Bool
  purchaseDate: Date?
  cost: Double?
}
```

and then you could carry on using a dictionary in the form of `[String: Event]` where the key is some sort of string for event ID, but it'd probably be easier for now to work with an array `[Event]`

You could then iterate through the array showing all the events (or filter to get specific ones) and then set the screen up accordingly, for example if `event` is an item from the array

```
eventNameField.text = event.name
if purchased, let date = event.purchaseDate, let cost = event.cost {
  purchasedDateField.text = "\(date)" //would really be a dateFormatted date
  costFiled.text = "\(cost)"
}
purchaseButton.isHidden = event.purchased
cancelButton.isHidden = !event.purchased
```